# MapQuest Directions API counts transaction for Geocoding

Tags: api, directions, mapquest

I generated free key for MapQuest API (15,000 free transactions per month). I'm only going to use Directions API and nothing else. What is important that I only want to use it with specified GPS coordinates - so I don't need Geocoding feature.

When I'm sending a request to MapQuest webService `/optimizedroute` they charge this as 1 Directions transaction (which is OK), but they also count N Geocoding transaction (N is number of points in route request).

I'm little confused because I don't provide address string but GPS coordinates - I have no idea why they are charging transaction for Geocoding.

Here you have my example requests (they count geocoding for this 2 variants - no matter if I use string GPS coordinates or JSON LatLng objects) :

1.

```
curl -X POST -H "Content-Type: application/json" -v -d '{"locations": [{"latLng":{"lat": 51.129044, "lng": 17.045847}}, {"latLng":{"lat": 51.107062, "lng": 17.032286}}, {"latLng":{"lat": 51.053140, "lng": 16.974779}}, {"latLng":{"lat": 51.077520, "lng": 17.065245}}, {"latLng":{"lat": 51.141539, "lng": 17.087733}}, {"latLng":{"lat": 51.102643, "lng": 17.087389}}, {"latLng":{"lat": 51.122903, "lng": 17.030741}}, {"latLng":{"lat": 51.129044, "lng": 17.045847}}], "routeType": "shortest", "options": {"unit": "k", "narrativeType": "none", "fullShape": true}}' http://www.mapquestapi.com/directions/v2/optimizedroute?key=KEY
```

2.

```
curl -X POST -H "Content-Type: application/json" -v -d '{"locations": ["51.129044,17.045847", "51.107062,17.032286", "51.053140,16.974779", "51.077520,17.065245", "51.141539,17.087733", "51.102643,17.087389", "51.122903,17.030741, "51.129044,17.045847"], "routeType": "shortest", "options": {"unit": "k", "narrativeType": "none", "fullShape": true}}' http://www.mapquestapi.com/directions/v2/optimizedroute?key=KEY
```

Does anyone has an idea why they are charging me for Geocoding service which I'm not using ? Or maybe you know how I should use their Directions API to not charge me for Geocoding ?

Greetings.

Comment: where do you see how many transactions they charge?

Comment: @Tahlor When you are in Map Quest developer console just click My applications -> Click on your Application and choose Transaction Report.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By default, when you pass in a latlng to the routing API, it will attempt to reverse geocode the latlng point and return additional address data for each point in the route. You can set the doReverseGeocode to false parameter in the json options parameter to stop this from happening.

Try this:

curl -X POST -H "Content-Type: application/json" -v -d '{"locations": ["51.129044,17.045847", "51.107062,17.032286", "51.053140,16.974779", "51.077520,17.065245", "51.141539,17.087733", "51.102643,17.087389", "51.122903,17.030741, "51.129044,17.045847"], "routeType": "shortest", "options": {**"doReverseGeocode": false**, "unit": "k", "narrativeType": "none", "fullShape": true}}'  http://www.mapquestapi.com/directions/v2/optimizedroute?key=KEY

Comment: I've made a request and I'm waiting to see if they count me a transactions for Geocoding in Developer console. I'll let you know if it's right solution.

Comment: You were right ! I have only one transaction count just for routing and geocoding transaction count is 0 ! Thank you a lot !